# Updating render process from UDP socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, electron

I am completely new to electron and node.js and currently trying to implement an electron application which is going to update some gauges, charts (possibly in multiple windows) according to values received from a udp socket. now i wondering what is the best design pattern for such task according to render/main process methodology of electron?